# Is there a CLI way to list NuGet package updates?

Tags: nuget, command-line-interface

In Visual Studio, I can right-click the solution, and follow the `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...` option to view referenced packages that have updates.

[image: Nuget - Solution - Updates]

What I'd like to be able to do is to obtain this same information, but from the CLI - either by running a NuGet CLI command or a NuGet PowerShell command.  Just a list of packages with updates available, with the current and latest versions would be sufficient.

I've looked through the documentation for both the NuGet CLI and NuGet Powershell, but can't see any candidate commands.

Is this possible?  How does the Visual Studio UI pull this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess Visual Studio is doing this by running two PowerShell commands. First `Get-Package`, that will list all packages in your project/solution, and then `Get-Package -Updates` that will list only packages with available updates. After that you can compare two lists, and you will have both current version and latest version. Link to documentation: [Get-Package (Package Manager Console in Visual Studio)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-get-package)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use this command within the package manager console of your solution to get the output you need:

```
Get-Package -Updates  | Select-Object Id, Version, @{Name="CurrentVersion"; Expression ={(Get-Package -filter $_.Id)[0].Versions.Version.ToString()}}
```

Should get only those packages needing updated and the current version installed.